# Dealing with async code in the aws-cdk in typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, aws-cdk

With async code in typescript with the aws-cdk, does anyone have a nice way/pattern to deal with resolving promises, and `app.syth()`?
Best I can think of is something like:

```
const promise = new PipelineStack(app, 'pipeline', config)
if (promise){
    promise.resolve(foo =>
        app.synth()
    )
} else {
    app.synth()
}
```

If I could I would just make is synchronous

Comment: I ended up with just returning a blank promise, with something like: `await prom.then( results=> {
            console.log(results)
            app.synth()
        })`

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code to the below code.

```
new PipelineStack(app, 'pipeline', config).then(
    foo => app.synth(),
    error => console.log(error)
);
```

You don't need to catch the promise. just handle the resolved value(`foo`).